# How to check if a script is loading external data?

Tags: javascript, external, cdata

I have this piece of code in a web site:

```
<div id="test">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    parameter1 = 'whatever1';
    parameter2 = 'whatever2';
    parameter3 = 'whatever3';
    etc.
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
  <script src='external js file'></script>
</div>
```

This code is used to load an image in that site from an external source. When they (whoever they are) configure the external source properly, the div 'test' will show an image. If not, div will be blank.

Ok, now let's suppose that another div in that site must show a certain content depending if the image is loaded, and a different content if not.

The external source is not accessible/editable, so it's unknown if they (whoever they are) are sending data for a image to be load or not.

So, is there a way to foreknow/detect in the code if the div 'test' is loading data?

**Edit 04/12/2016**

Finally I have used this, thanks to cFreed suggestion:

```
var target = document.getElementById('test');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //stuff;
  });    
});
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what the external script *might* result in?

Comment: Can you edit the fetcher code? It would be easiest to monitor or throw events from the fetch request, and populate the second div based on the request's status/result, rather than trying to make the second div react to the contents of the first div.

Comment: Hi ScottMarcus and TheJim01. The div 'test' code is quite similar to Option 3 shown in http://support.pencidesign.com/forums/topic/inserting-video-on-post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Here is a very simple application for your case.

```
var observerConfig = {childList: true}, // only notify when children added
    targets = {
      test: false,
      ...other <div>s to observe
    },
    target, elem, observer;

for (var target in targets) {
  elem = document.getElementById(target);

  // create and activate an observer instance
  observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // here we assume that the only changes are children addition
      // so we don't look at anything more precise
      targets[elem] = true;
    });
    observer.observe(elem, observerConfig);
  });
}

// then you can test targets['someTarget'] to know if it had been populated
```

Comment: Thanks, cFreed. Gonna study your idea (a bit elevated for just a newbie as me) and I'll tell you ;)

Comment: @b1919676 Be quiet: not so elevated. I didn't even know it exists a week ago, and had some test to see it's easy to use. By chance your question appears right next after that!